# Redraw Xamarin (Android) Slider when Min/Max updated

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've got a Xamarin slider whose `Maximum` value is being changed dynamically, and I'd like it to redraw on the screen after updates.

Everything works as expected on iOS, but Android doesn't redraw the slider until the next time the user interacts with it.

I expected that this platform-dependent behavior was call for a custom renderer. I can capture the PropertyChangedEvent that I want to trigger the redraw, but I haven't been able to actually redraw the slider.

Here's what I have so far on the renderer. I've tried varying combinations of the commented-out code, but I'm failing to actually trigger a redraw. (Debugging shows that the code is being reached, it's just not redrawing the screen.)

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Slider), typeof(MySliderRenderer))]

namespace MyProject.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class MySliderRenderer : SliderRenderer
    {
        public MySliderRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            // this.SetWillNotDraw(false);
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Slider.Maximum) || e.PropertyName == nameof(Slider.Minimum))
            {

                // Control.PostInvalidate();
                // Control.Invalidate();
                // Control.ForceLayout();
                // Control.PerformClick();
                // Control.RefreshDrawableState();

                // PostInvalidate();
                // Invalidate();
                // ForceLayout();
                // PerformClick();
                // RefreshDrawableState();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I force a `View` to redraw on-demand (or shortly thereafter) when the built-in data bindings fail to trigger updates the way I'd expect?

Comment: have you considered implementing a custom property change event pattern in order to force a redraw when the maximum value is changed rather than using the element change event that's exposed by the control. In fact is there no event that says something like valuechanged ?

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt I'm not sure I follow. I can already detect *when* I want to force a redraw, it's the redraw itself that's being elusive. Wouldn't implementing a custom event leave me with the same problem?

Comment: Apologies I don't think I was very clear, I've posted an answer with a possible solution, I haven't had chance to test it, but it should work in theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue (less an issue I guess and more of a hang up of Androids event based system) that android developers come across from time to time. I've seen it myself when working on Xamarin.Android native solutions. There's an interesting article [here](http://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-app-text-not-updating) that sort of talks around the underlying issue in some detail. Admittedly it talks about other controls like text boxes and buttons, but the principle is essentially the same.

> Android doesn't redraw the
>   slider until the next time the user interacts with it.

The article explains this fairly well. Having a look at the native Java for the UISlider suggest that you could try setting the max value and then straight afterwards setting the existing UISlider value as whatever it already is, that should force a redraw. It's not ideal but it should be a quick workaround for the time being.

The value change event that's triggered should force android to process the apps pending UI events.

Comment: It seems Android is too clever by half. From what I can tell, it won't redraw the slider unless its Value has changed, so `Value = Value` doesn't have any effect. I've got a hack working where I add a tiny amount to the value, and then trigger the related PropertyChangedEvent. That feels like a hacked solution, but it'll work for now.

Comment: @bpatterson no problem that seems like a sensible thing to do. If I get chance I'll see if I can come up with a better solution for you and amend my answer accordingly.